# ffmpeg shell output goes to php header?

Tags: php, header, ffmpeg, cgi, exec

I am trying to use ffmpeg from php script, ex.:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f ogg -y output.ogv >out.txt')
```

Let's assume it works, it actually doesn't for multiple reasons, but it's going to be solved by hosting provider as I have no way to change any config or so.

What seems strange is that out.txt is 0kb all the time, instead after php script finishes its work I get output like one below:

```
Malformed header from CGI script:
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on May 10 2013 16:31:05 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC) 20130502 (prerelease) configurati
(......)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[vp8 @ 0x13e8d00] alloc_buffer: av_image_alloc() failed
[vp8 @ 0x13e8d00] get_buffer() failed!
sh: line 1: 1540 Segmentation fault ffmpeg -i ../uploads/videomod_m_7/433c3f8b9b0cc0f6cbdebba5263ff71809811c20o.webm -f ogg -y ../uploads/videomod_m_7/test2.ogv > out.txt
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably ffmpeg is outputting on standard error, try

```
exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f ogg -y output.ogv &>out.txt')
```

to also redirect stderr to out.txt.